# Powershell: is there some hacky subroutine implementation?

Tags: powershell, subroutine

I was wondering if there is some way to call (or load) a function located lower in the script execution path.

I wrote a script to run deployment and as one of the last steps, the script parses web.config making a ton of changes based on configuration file. A feature request came in, asking for a switch to generate the web.config without actual deployment.

The only way I can think of doing it, is making all the parsing logic into a gigantic function, and loading it at the start of the script. However, that approach will make the script horribly ugly. Nor do I want to carve out all the logic into another script and dot sourcing it.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reading another 30 or so articles and decided to simply bracket the functionality and move it up higher in the script, then dot source the function from inside the script.

Thanks.

Comment: Something different than what i suggested?

Comment: Well, the script is close to a 1000 lines with numerous functions inside, so making it two functions isn't really an option. I was hoping to leave everything as is, and simply call a function in a subroutine manner, without having to load it first. Unfortunately, that does not seem possible. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Make it 2 functions one for deploy one for webconfig use a seperate function to check for switches and call functions based on those variables.

dc